# SQL ZOO List each continent and the name of the country that comes first alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql, correlated-subquery

Im confused why it could not be

```
Select x.continent, x.name
From world x
Where x.name <= ALL (select y.name from world y where x.name=y.name)
ORDER BY name
```

Can anyone please explain to me why it has to be x.continent=y.continent and not x.name=y.name ?

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSkFT.png)

Comment: You need to provide more background for your question.  What result are you trying to achieve that made "it" has to be `x.continent=y.continent`? Is it because when using `x.name=y.name ` you are not getting the result you desire of? or is it because you are getting an error? Please be specific about your question.

Comment: @O.KOO If I used x.name=y.name, the answer would be incorrect.

Comment: well, what is your desired answer/result?

Comment: @O.KOO From the table (the picture that I have attached ) I have to query out by listing each continent and the name of the country that comes first alphabetically. This is a question from  SQLZOO.

Comment: If you just want a list of each continent and the name of the country and order by country name alphabetically then you won't even need the WHERE clause.

Comment: @O.KOO Of course there is a need for the where clause. It needs to query only the " FIRST COUNTRY IN EACH CONTINENT" not every country in each continent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

when you use `x.name=y.name` you are comparing country name from x with the country name from y if both instances have the same country name. That basically would just return you the full table x.

You want to use `x.continent=y.continent` because you only want to compare the country name of an instance from x with the country name of an instance from y if they share the same continent.

Let me illustrate this step by step with an example:
Here we have a table world and I populated with some data:

```
world: 

Select  x.continent, x.name
From world x
ORDER BY  name

continent       name
Asia            Afghanistan
Europe          Albania
Africa          Algeria  
Europe          Andorra
Africa          Angola
SouthAmerica    Bolivia
SouthAmerica    Brazil
Europe          Hungary
Asia            Japan
Africa          Nigeria
SouthAmerica    Peru
Asia            Taiwan
```

when you execute this query without the WHERE clause in your subquery:

```
Select  x.continent, x.name
From world x
Where x.name <= ALL (select y.name from world y)
ORDER BY name
```

you get this

```
continent   name
Asia        Afghanistan
```

This is because the where clause filtered out all but one country

```
where x.name <= (Afghanistan,Taiwan,Japan,
                 Albania,Hungary,Algeria,Nigeria,Andorra,
                 Angola,Bolivia,Peru,Brazil)
```

and namely, the country name who comes first alphabetically which is Afghanistan.

but since we want to get the first country in *each continent* we will add `x.continent=y.continent` to our subquery

```
Select  x.continent, x.name
From world x
Where x.name <= ALL (select y.name from world y where x.continent=y.continent)
ORDER BY name
```

what is happening underneath is that now we are only comparing the country name of an instance from x with the country name of an instance from y if they share the same continent. So use continent of Asia for example:

Japen gets filtered out because
`Japan <= All(Afghanistan,Taiwan,Japan)` is false since Japan is not less or equal to Afghanistan (A comes before J)

Taiwan gets filtered out because
`Taiwan <= All(Afghanistan,Taiwan,Japan)` is false since Taiwan is not less or equal to Afghanistan.

Afghanistan does not get filtered out because 
`Afghanistan <= All(Afghanistan,Taiwan,Japan)` is true since Afghanistan is equal to Afghanistan

However, if you use `x.name=y.name` in your subquery then you are essentially comparing each country to itself and they will all get included in your final result set because all country name equals to the country name of itself.

I hope this help and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted."

Comment: @O KOO Thanks. Appreciate your explanation:D

Comment: a note: `ORDER BY name` has nothing to do with this

Answer (score 15):

I tried this and it also works:

```
SELECT continent, MIN(name)
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct answer:

```sql
Select continent,name 
from world x
Where x.name <= ALL(select y.name from world y
                    where x.continent=y.continent)
ORDER BY continent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select A.continent, A.name 
 from
 (Select  x.continent, x.name, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY x.continent ORDER BY x.name 
 asc)AS Rank  
 From world x
 group by  x.continent, x.name)A
 where
 Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is easy as min func will return first word in alphabetic order.

`SELECT continent, name FROM world x WHERE name = (SELECT min(name) FROM world y WHERE x.continent = y.continent );`

Answer (score 0):

This also produce the correct answer.

```
SELECT continent, name
FROM world a
WHERE name <= ALL(SELECT name FROM world b
               WHERE a.continent = b.continent)
```

Answer (score 0):

One note here - the ORDER BY is unnecessary for a correct answer to this problem, for the simplest solution all you need is:

```
SELECT continent, name
FROM world w1
WHERE w1.name <= ALL(SELECT name 
                       FROM world w2
                       WHERE w1.continent=w2.continent)
```

Answer (score 0):

List each continent and the name of the country that comes first alphabetically.

> Select continent, name
> from world x
> where name in (select min(name)
> from world y
> where  x.continent= y.continent)

Comment: You've provided a code sample, that's great. But it might get overlooked because it lacks the proper formatting.  To change that, have a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), especially at the sections titled "Code blocks" and "Syntax highlighting for code".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    continent, name
FROM
    world x
WHERE
    name <= ALL(SELECT name FROM world y WHERE x.continent=y.continent ORDER BY name )
ORDER BY continent
```

return a list of ordered country names, then return the first entry of this list, finally order the outer select query by continent.

Answer (score 0):

Another method use rank() funciton also works

```
select continent, name
from
(
    select continent, name, rank() over (partition by continent order by continent, name) as rn
    from world
    group by continent, name
    order by rn
) as a 
where rn = 1
order by continent
```

Comment: while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You Can query by this way

```sql
    SELECT MIN(continent), MIN(name) 
    FROM world
    GROUP By continent
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
with new as (
    select continent, name , row_number() over (partition by continent order by name) as row 
    from world
)

select continent,name
from new
where row = 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and add a little explaining text how it works and why it is different from the others given.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple query that will work for the question above:

Select continent, min(name)
From world
group by continent ;

Comment: This answer was already [given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65753241/16019058), and this doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select continent, name
from world x
where name = 
(select name from world y where x.continent= y.continent order by name limit 1)
```

Just order the elements in the correlated subquery and the first of them using limit.

Answer (score 0):

select continent, min(name) from world
group by continent

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT continent, name 
FROM world as x
WHERE name = ALL(SELECT min(name)
                 FROM world y
                 WHERE x.continent = y.continent);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain more details, such that others can learn from it